# how can I call a method only one time in a class? (first time when add "new")

Tags: javascript, html, oop

I have a long code with a lot method, but since I am on stackoverflow I will add to you a simple minimal example here (is not the final, but I hope show you the bug):

I have a code like this:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.myMethod();
  }

  myMethod() {
    console.log("hello world!")
  }
}

new MyClass();
```

and this code is ok.

the method runs once.

but if I call it more than 2+ times it will run the method another time.

```js
/* other code  */
new MyClass();
new MyClass();
new MyClass();
new MyClass();
new MyClass();

// wrong output:
hello world
hello world 
hello world
...

// desired output (only one time)
hello world
```

if you are interested in why run one time. this is because I want that the class created some Ui elements at the first but then get the generated ui and change the things with the given parameters in constructor

Comment: Why would you create more than one instance of a UI element? It is the class constructor that is running multiple times.

Comment: Look into the "singleton" design pattern. This may solve your issue, but I am not positive.

Comment: @StephenKlein I have that user can change some values by creating new class, I found the solution: is using "static" thanks anyways

Comment: @StephenKlein I will see the singleton to learn, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> check this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

there is a keyword for classes that do this thing called [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

```js
class MyClass {
  // no () just static and { your code }
  static {
    console.log("called once");
  }

  myOtherMethod() {
    console.log("run when I want or every time")
  }
}

/* other code  */
new MyClass();
new MyClass();
new MyClass();
new MyClass();
new MyClass();
```